Django DRF - Accessing data from POST request forwarded through ngrok
I'm working on a Django REST framework (DRF) API that receives data forwarded from an external endpoint through ngrok. Here's the relevant view code:
Python
class MessageReceiver(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def post(self, request, org_id, channel_name):
        data = request.data
        if data:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "data": data
                },
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        return Response(data={'message': 'No data received'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

My question is: since this is a POST request, I'm unable to access the original forwarded data directly. As I understand, POST requests require a payload to be sent along with the request. How can I effectively access and process the data within request.data in this scenario before I have to hit the endpoint again?

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] set this or  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['YOUR MACHINE IP'                  '0ffa-39-37-182-231.ngrok-free.app']

try above Or if again you unable to access data, then make sure you set dajngo-cors
